# What are the possible impetuses for loss of Middle English shwa?

Tags: english, phonology, historical-linguistics, sociolinguistics, germanic-languages

I'm wondering what some possible catalysts/ reasons for loss of final -e `/ǝ/` in Middle English might have been (For instance, OE `/tɑlu/` > ME `/taːlǝ/` > MnE tale `/teɪl/`).

I'm wondering because to my knowledge, all other Germanic languages have retained final *shwa* as part of their inflectional system (Dutch *"een klein meisje, het klein**e** meisje"*).

I'm interested in social as well as linguistic factors.

Comment: Why are you comparing English nouns with Dutch adjectives? Dutch has done the same thing with its nouns: the Middle Dutch `tale` is `taal` today.

Comment: Wasn't English profoundly influenced by French? I'd suppose French was a softer language than original Germanic ones.

Answer (score 3):

David Crystal (ref. 1995:32) suggests a possible explanation why such reduction may have occurred:

1. the articulatory stress started to fall on the first syllable;
2. such stress pattern has introduced difficulties to the **audibility** of the inflectional endings;
3. therefore, inflectional endings *-en, -on,* and *-an* first reduced to *schwa*;
4. and subsequently disappeared.

There are more details in [this answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/6906/1009).